# Как переопределить ключевое слово "if" и символ "+" в С++?

Tags: c++, qt

Как переопределить ключевое слово "if" и символ "+"  в С++ ?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Вот тут надо переопределить ИФ и плюсик" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Вы просто хотите вывести слово `if`  и `+`? Если нет то никак

Comment: В С++ невозможно "переопределить ключевое слово" или "переопределить символ". Таких понятий нет в принципе. Потрудитесь описать яснее, что вам нужно сделать.

Comment: Неясно, что подразумевается под "переопределить ключевое слово", но могу предположить, что речь идет про `#define esli if`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это называется "перегрузка операторов". "+" перегрузить можно. "if" не перегружается в принципе. Его можно переопределить с помощью  #define, но это будет уже совсем жесть. Такое никогда не делают. 
https://habrahabr.ru/post/132014/